# Topology of K3 as a sum of two abelian fibrations.

Tags: tag-removed, gt.geometric-topology, k3-surfaces, elliptic-surfaces, intersection-theory

Let $E$ be a blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at 9-points in the bases locus of a pencil of elliptic curves (A $T^2$ fibration over $S^2$).

K3 surfaces is obtained by removing a fiber from two copies of $E$ and gluing along the boundaries.

How do we realize 22 second homology classes of K3, in terms of 10 second homology classes of $E$. I know this is classic but I could not find a reference.

Comment: The construction is mentioned in arxiv.org/pdf/1201.0930.pdf. They reference the string theory paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0308106v1.pdf.

Comment: They have a discussion before gluing (on the union), I could not find anything there discussing what happens after gluing. I remember once Szabo told us about that and he was using some standard book on surfaces.

Comment: Try to look at the book of Gompf and Stipsicz

Comment: This might be a good solution. I should try it tomorrow.